# python3 - to_parquet data format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parquet

dataframe with the datetime64[ns] column as parquet using pandas.to_parquet and read the parquet file, the datetime64[ns] column is converted to unixtimestamp.

eg. 2022-10-05 19:31:57.894835 -> 1664998317894835000

Is it not possible to save the datetime64[ns] column as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime64[ns]` format of a pd.DataFrame is a dtype specific of Pandas, or to be more precise, of NumPy.

This is not comparable to the types supported by the [parquet-format types](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format#types) source: Apache's official parquet docs.

You should also check which engine you are using to generate the parquet file. According to pandas [API reference of the to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html), if not explicitly specified, it probably defaults to `pyarrow`.

If `pyarrow` is your engine, then this type differences are holding:

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html#type-differences

Always arrow documentation suggest the [proper handing](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html#date-types):

> If you want to use NumPy’s datetime64 dtype instead, pass `date_as_object=False`:

```
In [26]: s2 = pd.Series(arr.to_pandas(date_as_object=False))

In[27]:  s2.dtype
Out[27]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Bonus track >> If reading / reloading of is performed in Spark, you can later use datetime functions in order to convert the unix timestamp, [spark-sql datetime](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).